# C - How to alter a pointer outside a function?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

I'm studying data structures in C by myself and i'm trying to implement a linked list but I do not understand how to alter the starting pointer when a new value is added. This is my actual code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *transverse_list(struct node *start) {
    struct node *current_node;
    struct node *last;

    current_node -> next = start;

    while(current_node -> next != NULL) {
        printf("Current value: %d\n", current_node -> value);
        current_node = current_node -> next;
    }

    last = current_node;

    return last;
}

void add_element(int value, struct node *start) {
    struct node *new_node, *ptr_new_node;

    new_node = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    ptr_new_node = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if(start == NULL) {
        printf("start: %d\n", start);
        new_node -> value = value;
        new_node -> next = NULL;
        start = new_node;
        printf("start: %d\n", start);
        printf("Pointer value: %d\n", start -> value);
    } else {
        struct node *last;
        last = transverse_list(start);
        new_node -> value = value;
        ptr_new_node = NULL;
        new_node -> next = ptr_new_node;
    }
}

int main() {
    struct node *start = NULL;

    add_element(2, start);
    add_element(3, start);
    add_element(5, start);
    add_element(7, start);
    add_element(11, start);
    add_element(13, start);

    transverse_list(start);

    return 0;
}
```

Which prints:

```
start: 0
start: 7084208  
Pointer value: 2
start: 0        
start: 7084240  
Pointer value: 3
start: 0        
start: 7084272
Pointer value: 5
start: 0
start: 7084304
Pointer value: 7
start: 0
start: 7083968
Pointer value: 11
start: 0
start: 7084000
Pointer value: 13
```

I previously made this code for another exercise, whose sum() function alters the value of the pointer in the main function.

```
void sum(int*, int*, int*);

int main() {
    int num1, num2;
    int *total;

    num1 = 10;
    num2 = 15;

    sum(&num1, &num2, &total);
    printf("Sum: %d\n", total);

    return 0;
}

void sum(int *a, int *b, int *t) {
    *t = *a + *b;
}
```

Which prints:

```
Sum: 25
```

I tried to pass the start pointer to the add_element function (example: add_element(2, &start)), but it gives me a segmentation fault.

Why does the first example not work like the second example?

Comment: You need to use a pointer to start, `add_element(2, &start);` to update to value of start. Minor remark don't cast malloc result

Comment: You never change `start` in main.  If you want to modify a variable in the caller, you have to pass the address of the variable.  That is, you should call `add_element(2, &start)` and change the prototype of `add_element` to take a `struct node **`

Comment: Either pass the address of  `start` as in `add_element(2, &start);`  or use a return value like `start = add_element(2, start);`.  Change `add_element()` accordingly.  Your choice.

Comment: _Side note:_ For best style, _never_ do (e.g.): `new_node -> value` but _always_ do: `new_node->value`

Comment: Can you provide a more specific question? It might help to better understand what expectation you have for the output of your code.

Comment: hey ppl, thanx a lot for the answers and tips, i can better understand now how to deal with pointers. Ypu're amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
void sum(int*, int*, int*);

int main() {
    int num1, num2;
    int *total;

    num1 = 10;
    num2 = 15;

    sum(&num1, &num2, &total);
    printf("Sum: %d\n", total);

    return 0;
}

void sum(int *a, int *b, int *t) {
    *t = *a + *b;
}
```

is incorrect because in this statement

```
*t = *a + *b;
```

you are trying to assign a pointer with an integer without casting and in this statement

```
printf("Sum: %d\n", total);
```

you are using incorrect conversion specifier `%d` for outputting a pointer.

These functions

```
struct node *transverse_list(struct node *start) {
    struct node *current_node;
    struct node *last;

    current_node -> next = start;

    while(current_node -> next != NULL) {
        printf("Current value: %d\n", current_node -> value);
        current_node = current_node -> next;
    }

    last = current_node;

    return last;
}

void add_element(int value, struct node *start) {
    struct node *new_node, *ptr_new_node;

    new_node = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    ptr_new_node = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if(start == NULL) {
        printf("start: %d\n", start);
        new_node -> value = value;
        new_node -> next = NULL;
        start = new_node;
        printf("start: %d\n", start);
        printf("Pointer value: %d\n", start -> value);
    } else {
        struct node *last;
        last = transverse_list(start);
        new_node -> value = value;
        ptr_new_node = NULL;
        new_node -> next = ptr_new_node;
    }
}
```

do not make sense, invoke undefined behavior and produce memory leaks.

What you need is to change the pointer `start` defined in main in the function `add_element`. In this case you need to pass the pointer by reference to the function. In C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through pointer.

The function `add_element` can be declared and defined the following way

```
int add_element( struct node **start, int value ) 
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->value = value;
        new_node->next  = NULL;

        while( *start != NULL ) start = &( *start )->next;

        *start = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}
```

As I understand the function `transverse_list` is used to output the list. It can be declared and defined the following way

```
FILE * transverse_list( struct node *start, FILE *fp ) 
{
    for ( struct node *current = start; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        fprintf( fp, "%d -> ", current->value );
    }

    fputs( "null", fp );

    return fp;
}
```

And in main you can write

```
struct node *start = NULL;

add_element( &start, 2 );
add_element( &start, 3 );
add_element( &start, 5 );
add_element( &start, 7 );
add_element( &start, 11 );
add_element( &start, 13 );

transverse_list( start, stdout );
```

Pay attention to that this typedef

```
typedef struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};
```

does not make a great sense because it does not introduce an alias for the type `struct node`. Instead you could write for example

```
typedef struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *next;
} node;
```

Or you could declare just the structure

```
struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node 
{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};

int add_element( struct node **start, int value ) 
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->value = value;
        new_node->next  = NULL;

        while( *start != NULL ) start = &( *start )->next;

        *start = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}

FILE * transverse_list( struct node *start, FILE *fp ) 
{
    for ( struct node *current = start; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        fprintf( fp, "%d -> ", current->value );
    }

    fputs( "null", fp );

    return fp;
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct node *start = NULL;

    add_element( &start, 2 );
    add_element( &start, 3 );
    add_element( &start, 5 );
    add_element( &start, 7 );
    add_element( &start, 11 );
    add_element( &start, 13 );

    transverse_list( start, stdout );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2 -> 3 -> 5 -> 7 -> 11 -> 13 -> null
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You not only aswered the main question, but clarified another things in the code. Thanks to you and to the other people that have answered, now i have a better understanding of what is going on in the code and how to deal with pointeres. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

when adding to, deleting, or sorting a linked list, the value in the 'head' pointer (your starting pointer) can change.

For the called function to change that pointer contents, it must be passed the address of the pointer  --or-- return the new contents of that pointer and the returned value is assigned to the 'head' pointer